# ScriptDb and Google Visualization API

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a web app that data is submitted from a Ui embedded in a Google Site and saved in a spreadsheet. I am thinking about switching to scriptDB instead, but I am unsure about querying and displaying data dynamically. The last time I checked it was not possible to refresh a sites page from within a script, so as a work around I wrote a .html page with javascript that accesses the spreadsheet via the key and uses the Visualization DataTables to produce a quick and nicely formatted query. I would like to retain this functionality if possible. Could anyone make some possible suggestions?

Regards,

Shawn

Comment: Have you got more details. I am not clear on what functionality you want to retain. ...that said .... I think this should let you do the refresh. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service

Comment: Thanks for the response. The query is pretty much an html form with drop downs and text fields users can choose criteria that is then put into a query string and submitted when a button is clicked. Once the query is sent using the Google Visualization API the results are returned and then put into a datatable that is displayed on the page.

Comment: The purpose being that users can view submissions pertaining to certain criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable today via UiApp (see the [Charts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_charts) api, and note that you can add a Chart to a UiApp).

Comment: Ah ok. That may be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To auto refresh:
You can use CheckBox.setValue(value, fireEvents) - but you may hit quota issues (there is an example somewhere around). If you hit quota issues, then I suspect HTML service is your best option. It also gives you better control.

Comment: I will check out the HTML service. I have had some problems in the past due to Caja stripping out code.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2241) is an open item requesting expanded Charts service integration with Gviz.

Although, there is limited integration at present, it needs to be expanded to group variables in tables to facilitate basic count and sum operations.

I suggest you “star” the issue to vote for it and to be notified of new developments.